# Generic DAO and types of business objects -- ways to reduce code

Tags: java, dao

I've wrote the following GenericDAO as in the code below

```
abstract public class DAO <T extends AbstractBusinessObject> {

// CRUD: create, read, update, delete 

public abstract T create(Class<T> abObj);

public abstract T read();

public abstract void update(T abObj);

public abstract void delete(T abObj);
```

But occasionaly when I implement custom DAO (e.g. DAOinMemory) and its methods like `create` I have to 
write the following code:

```
 public T create(Class<T> abstractObjectType) {

    IDGenerator IDGenerator = IDGenerator.getInstance();

    if (BusinessEntityFirst.class.isAssignableFrom(abstractObjectType)) {
        BigInteger id = IDGenerator.getID();
        BusinessEntityFirst bef = new BusinessEntityFirst(id);
        return (T) bef;
    }

    if (BusinessEntitySecond.class.isAssignableFrom(abstractObjectType)) {
        BigInteger id = IDGenerator.getID();
        BusinessEntitySecond bes = new BusinessEntitySecond(id);
        return (T) bes;
    }

    if (BusinessEntityThird.class.isAssignableFrom(abstractObjectType)) {
        BigInteger id = IDGenerator.getID();
        BusinessEntityThird bet = new BusinessEntityThird(id);
        return (T) bet;
    }

    if (abstractObjectType == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Can't create instance for:" + abstractObjectType);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I see that some parts of the `create`-method implementation look like *Spaghetti code* (three if-conditions with `.isAssignableFrom` method) and I can't do anything to overcome it. Could you advice something how to make a common piece of code for this parts in order to get rid of Spaghetti code?

Comment: I'd make separate DAO classes for the business classes (typed accordingly). You accomplish absolutely nothing by attempting to cram them all in one single class, as you've noticed yourself.

Comment: Can you have that abstract class extended in a class say C and then extend the class C for your classes. Then define that create method in class C and use them in your extended classes. Does that sound good ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [Factory Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) and [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm) and that should help you to design your code. In your case Abstract Factory Pattern will be a better choice of design.

Factory design pattern deals with creation of Objects according to need. So in your case you will have a object generator class which will generate required objects fro the factory.